# Google Play 64-bit requirement issue even i have provided 64 bit apk

Tags: android, google-play-console, armv7, armv8

I have been researching for the past 3 days and nights on this issue but whenever I am uploading android app bundle on Google Play Store but getting 64-bit requirement error on review.My app bundle is completely Java/Kotlin based with native support as some third party has dependency on it. I have included the support for all architecture armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 in gradle file also enabled split for the abi.

While creating a signed app bundle, in the analyzer it shows all the native support library in it(.so file under armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a,x86,x86_64 in lib folder).

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 21.
Even though I have added dependency for both 32/64 bit native code.

Here is Android App Bundles properties https://ibb.co/j66wn4S

**Gradle config I have added:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.12.1'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.name"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 74
        versionName "3.1"
        ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86', 'x86_64', "armeabi"
        renderscriptTargetApi 16
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "we54rew6r4ew654sdf4sdf54sdf4",
                                // Project number pulled from dashboard, local value is ignored.
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
    implementation 'com.github.kanytu:android-parallax-listview:v1.1'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.2.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:blurry:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.10.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.irozon.sneaker:sneaker:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.8.4'
    implementation 'pl.bclogic:pulsator4droid:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.yehiahd:FastSave-Android:1.0.6'
    implementation 'de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6'
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.5.1'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libx'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Do you have any file with the extension .bc in your App Bundle?

Comment: No i don't have the .BC file.

Comment: Any news on this ? Did you solve your problem ?